# generate maximum number of combinations

Tags: vba, algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm enabling to generate the full list of possible combinations from x given numbers.

Example:  possible combinations from `3 numbers (a, b,c)`:

`a`, `b`, `c` , `a +b` , `a + c` , `b + c` , `a+b+c`

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you meant generate possible combination of sum of numbers?

1. Start with an empty set `s = {0}`
2. For each number `a,b,c`:
   duplicate the existing set `s`, add each number to the duplicated set. Add the results back to `s`.

Example:

```
s = {0}
for a:
duplicate s, s' = {0}
add a to each of s', s' = {a}
add s' back to s, s = {0,a}

for b:
duplicate s, s' = {0,a}
add b to each of s' = {b,a+b}
add s' back to s, s= {0,a,b,a+b}

for c:
dupicate s, s' = {0,a,b,a+b}
add c to each of s' = {c,a+c,b+c,a+b+c}
add s' to s, s = {0,a,b,a+b,c,a+c,b+c,a+b+c}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the binary representation of the numbers from 0 to 2^x-1 as set membership. E.g., for ABC:

```
0 = 000 = {}
1 = 001 = {C}
2 = 010 = {B}
3 = 011 = {B,C}
4 = 100 = {A}
etc...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved!